# Cefsharp can work with offlinescreen and true window modes in the same applicaiton?

Tags: cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I hava a application, it's shell is winform with cefsharp,  there is an image which rendered by a cef offscreen process inside.

it seems to be working well... but, it is said that mixing rendering modes can lead to unknown bugs...

Comment: If you are using version `83.4.20` then it should be fine, older versions did have problems in certain circumstances.

Comment: ok，i have a try, thank you!